# An exercise about series and integral (together)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have never seen an exercise like this one and I'm really uncertain about the correct way to solve it...

> Evaluate $$I= \sum_{n=0}^{\inf}\oint_{\gamma}
>  \frac{(4s)^n}{s-4}cot(s)ds$$
>
> where $\gamma$ is the cirle of radius |2|, centered in s=0.

Clearly we have only one singularity (s=0) inside $\gamma$, but I don't know how to manage it... I can't use the Cauchy formula

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi j} \oint \frac {f(s)}{s-z}ds$$
because clearly the function is not in this form....

I can't do a Taylor expansion around the singularity...

Many thanks for your help

---

Following the sunggestion in the comments, I have tried 2 'different' ways, but in one case I have to impose a restriction, in the other one no restriction was needed... Which is the correct one?

**WAY 1:**

$$I= \sum_{n=0}^{\inf}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{(4s)^n}{s-4}cot(s)ds= \oint_{\gamma} \sum_{n=0}^{\inf} \frac{(4s)^n}{s-4}cot(s)ds = \oint_{\gamma} \sum_{n=0}^{\inf} {(4s)^n} \frac{1}{s-4}\frac{\cos (s)}{\sin(s)}ds=$$

$\displaystyle =\oint \frac{1}{1-4s}\frac{1}{s-4} \frac{\cos s}{\sin s}$ provided that |s|<1

Keeping in mind the $\gamma$ contour and the restriction, there is only one singularity, s=0. Applying the Theorems of residuals:

$$=2\pi j (\lim _{s->0} s \cdot \frac{1}{1-4s}\frac{1}{s-4} \frac{\cos s}{\sin s})=(-1/4)\cdot 2\pi j$$

**WAY 2:**

$$I= \sum_{n=0}^{\inf}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{(4s)^n}{s-4}cot(s)ds= \oint_{\gamma} \sum_{n=0}^{\inf} \frac{(4s)^n}{s-4}cot(s)ds =\oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{s-4}\frac{\cos s}{\sin s} +\oint_{\gamma}\sum_{n=1}^{\inf} \frac{(4s)^n}{s-4}cot(s)ds $$

but

$$\lim_{s->0} \frac{s^n}{\sin s}=\lim_{s->0} \frac{n s^{n-1}}{\cos s}=0$$

so s=0 is a removable discontinuity, the second integrand function is analytic and the value of the corresponding integral is zero (Cauchy's Theorem). So:

$$I= \oint_{\gamma} \frac{1}{s-4}\frac{\cos s}{\sin s} ds= 2\pi j \cdot (lim_{s->0} s \frac{1}{s-4} \frac{\cos s}{\sin s})=(-1/4)\cdot 2 \pi j$$

Comment: What is the center of this circle?

Comment: $\cot(s)$ has a singularity at $s=0,\pi,\ldots$. However $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}s\cot(s)-1=0$. So the singularity at 0 is removable when $n\geq 1$.

Comment: maybe try bringing the sigma into the integral and computing the series $\sum (4s)^n$ for the values of $s$ that it converges.

Comment: @kobe The center is s=0, thanks..

Comment: @AlexR.but the series starts from 0... I can't say "ok, the singularity is removable, so the funciotn is analytic, so the integral is 0"... Am I wrong?

Comment: the term with $n=0$ will give the only contribution to the above sum

Comment: @tired I have updated the question... thanks for your attention

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury Updated question.. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

First, 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{(4z)^n\cot z\,dz}{z-4}=\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{(4z)^n\cot z\,dz}{z-4},z=\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{(4z)^n\cot z\,dz}{z-4},z=-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-\frac{(2\pi)^n}{\frac{\pi}{2}-4}-\frac{(-2\pi)^n}{-\frac{\pi}{2}-4},
$$
since
$$
\mathrm{Res}\left(\cot z,\pm\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-1.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}\frac{(4z)^n\cot z\,dz}{z-4}
$$
diverges.